# Is there any way to turn scrollbar indicator of pageview to doted indicator in flutter and change the position?

Tags: flutter, scrollbar, indicator

I'm facing an issue with scrollbar indicator, as a newbie, I am quite unfamiliar with scrollbar indicator of flutter.

I want to Change the ScrollBar indicator shape/what it is to  the doted indicator, and I want to change it position to my desired position, without using any packages.

Is there any way to solve the problem?

[image: Actually I want Somethong Like this]

And Here my "messy" code -

---

```
Scrollbar(
  child: PageView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        // Container 1
        height: screenHeight * 0.76,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              height: screenHeight * 0.50,
              child: Image(
                image: AssetImage('assets/4351502.jpg'),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              height: screenHeight * 0.26,
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 30, 0, 0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text(
                      "Let's get started",
                      style: GoogleFonts.sniglet(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: Color(0xFF1D1E50),
                      ),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 12, 12, 0),
                    child: Text(
                      "Lorem ipsum dolor amet, consecetur\nadipiscing elit, eiusmod tempor.",
                      style: GoogleFonts.sniglet(
                        fontSize: 14,
                        height: 1.9,
                        color: Color(0xFFC6C8CA),
                      ),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        // Container 2
        height: screenHeight * 0.76,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              height: screenHeight * 0.50,
              child: Image(
                image: AssetImage('assets/4351502.jpg'),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              height: screenHeight * 0.26,
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 30, 0, 0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text(
                      "Let's get started",
                      style: GoogleFonts.sniglet(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: Color(0xFF1D1E50),
                      ),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 12, 12, 0),
                    child: Text(
                      "Lorem ipsum dolor amet, consecetur\nadipiscing elit, eiusmod tempor. 2",
                      style: GoogleFonts.sniglet(
                        fontSize: 14,
                        height: 1.9,
                        color: Color(0xFFC6C8CA),
                      ),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        // Container 3
        height: screenHeight * 0.76,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              height: screenHeight * 0.50,
              child: Image(
                image: AssetImage('assets/4351502.jpg'),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              height: screenHeight * 0.26,
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 30, 0, 0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text(
                      "Let's get started",
                      style: GoogleFonts.sniglet(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: Color(0xFF1D1E50),
                      ),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 12, 12, 0),
                    child: Text(
                      "Lorem ipsum dolor amet, consecetur\nadipiscing elit, eiusmod tempor. 3",
                      style: GoogleFonts.sniglet(
                        fontSize: 14,
                        height: 1.9,
                        color: Color(0xFFC6C8CA),
                      ),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: did you check this package: [https://pub.dev/packages/dots_indicato](https://pub.dev/packages/dots_indicator)

Comment: @Mehrdad Is it possible to do it without any packages as I mentioned in my question above?

Comment: @xahid_rocks Yes, Everything is possible, but that will take too much code So why to reinvent the wheel when there is already one,Therfore I will suggest you to use the DotsIndicator package for the dots which are shown below the image, and Use a pageController to control the position of the dots, when a page changes.

Comment: @Mukul, currently I am using smooth_page_indicator, doing the job at best,I am just curious about the property of the scrollbar and looking for a scope to reuse, like the kind of wheel I want.However, Thank you for your valuable insight.

Comment: @xahid_rocks you can see the code of package to find out how package do that.